# How to deduplicate item from graphql query?

Tags: graphql

For example I have an array return as

```
[
 {
  value: "v",
  time: "t"
},{
  value: "v",
  time: "t"
}, {
  value: "v-other",
  time: "t-other"
}
]
```

I would expect give me only

```
[
 {
  value: "v",
  time: "t"
}, {
  value: "v-other",
  time: "t-other"
}
]
```

How can I make a correct query?

Comment: Please provide more information. If it is the response from a resolver in your GraphQL API, you need to find the resolver that produces this data, and de-dupe it before returning the value.

Comment: @ReganKarlewicz It seems graphql doesn't provide a query to deduplicate the return? MySQL has something called DISTINCT.

Comment: GraphQL is not comparable to a database query language, and its responses are directly controlled by the implementing API. GraphQL usually sits in front of a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comment @ReganKarlewicz share, GraphQL shouldn't be treated as an database query language, we should use other tool, MySQL or Node functions to deduplicate the query result.